# Как вызвать HTML код, триггером в Google таблице

Tags: google-apps-script

Есть задача, в Google таблице вызвать триггером или каким либо автоматическим образом при определённом значении ячейки, HTML код.
При попытке вызвать таким образом

```
 function showDialog() {
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Win')
          .setWidth(4).setHeight(3);

      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Победа');
 }
```

Win.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, world!
  </body>
</html>
```

триггером таймера, выдаёт ошибку "Не удается вызвать функцию SpreadsheetApp.getUi() из этого контекстного меню"

при вызове вручную всё отлично работает. Как можно обойти эту ошибку?

Comment: Как задавать вопросы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Этот вопрос должен быть закрыт или переформулирован согласно правилам.

Comment: Да какая разница, всё равно вряд ли кто знает как это реализовать, и вообще вряд ли это возможно

Comment: Я знаю как это делается и знаю почему не работает.

Comment: Если так, в чём сложность ответить?

Comment: В чем сложность соблюдать правила? Или, типа, такая фея - что хочу, то и несу - взмахну палочкой, и будь что будет, авось, повезет! Если есть задача, то всегда найдется тот, кто сможет ее решить. Советую прочитать первый коммент еще раз.

Comment: Для тупого покажи, что я нарушил!

Comment: Ок. Основная проблема в том, что триггер должен быть зарегистрированным. Для ваших нужд необходимо использовать `onEdit` и `onChange`. Почему не работает, написано тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892964/force-ask-authorization-onopen-force-popup/44895775?noredirect=1#comment88727764_44895775. Это как бы и не баг и баг и не пойми что. Пример будет позже.

Comment: Спасибо, я идею понял и в другом проекте реализовал, работает отлично.

Comment: Но почему я пытался решить эту задачу через тригеры ... если я не ошибаюсь, то onEdit и onChange срабатывают у пользователя непосредственно производящего изменения(могу ошибаться), а мне необходимо, что бы скрипт запускался на "экране", то есть без действий из вне. А я так понимаю, что политика Гугла, запуск HTML модулей без действия пользователя не поощряет, но может это как то можно обойти.